# Deploy Android Apps wirelessly

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm an Android Developer.

Usually, I'm developing the apps on my phone via eclipse and USB cable. I'm wondering if there is a possibility to get eclipse installing the apps without cable, e.g. via internet or WLAN.

Comment: Check out [ADB WiFi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ryosoftware.adbw&hl=en), the problem is it requires a rooted device.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=623828&page=3) post on xda-developers, you can enable ADB over WiFi from the device with the commands. The only caveat is that you must have a rooted device to do this.

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port 5555
stop adbd
start adbd
```

And you can disable it and return ADB to listening on USB with

```
setprop service.adb.tcp.port -1
stop adbd
start adbd
```

If you have USB access already, it is even easier to switch to using WiFi.  From a command line on the computer that has the device connected via USB, issue the commands

```
adb tcpip 5555
adb connect 192.168.0.101:5555
```

To tell the ADB daemon return to listening over USB

```
adb usb
```

There are also several apps on the Android Market that automate this process.

Comment: This solution is just perfect!! Thank you very much.